# Gibbs Sampling for Auto-exponential model

Tags: r, self-study, bayesian

This question is taken from Chapter 6 of Bayesian Biostatistics [Lesaffre and Lawson, 2012, pp. 173]. Consider the following un-normalized joint density for an auto-exponential model [Besag, 1974]:

$p(y1, y2, y3)$ $∝$ $\exp${−$(y_{1}$ $+$ $y_{2}$ $+$ $y_{3}$ $+$ $\psi_{1,2}y_{1}y_{2}$ $+$ $\psi_{1,3}y_{1}y_{3}$ + $\psi_{2,3}y_{2}y_{3}$)

Where, $\psi{i,j} > 1$.

I am trying to implement a Gibbs sampler of this distribution in R.

```
Gibbs <- function(n, burnin=500){
  res <- matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = n)
  # initialise
  y_1 = 0
  y_2 = 0
  y_3 = 0
  
  psi12 = 0
  psi_13 = 0
  psi_23 = 0

  # ignore values after loop
  for(i in seq_len(burnin)){
    # unsure about params
    rate = 
    x = rgamma(3, shape=1, rate=rate)
    # unsure about params
    mean = 
    sd = 
    y = rnorm(3, mean=mean, sd=sd)
    
  }
  
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    rate = 
    x = rgamma(3, shape=1, rate=rate)
    mean = 
    sd = 
    y = rnorm(3, mean=mean, sd=sd)
    
    res[i, ] = x 
    
  } 
  data.frame(res)
}
```

I am looking for some insight into how to derive the correct parameters for the `rgamma`, `rnorm` functions from the above model.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *implement in R*? What do you want to implement?

Comment: @Onyambu I am trying to implement a Gibbs sampler of this distribution in R.

Comment: @Onyambu: A Gibbs sampler only requires the full conditionals $p(y_1|y_2,y_3)$, $p(y_2|y_1,y_3)$, $p(y_3|y_2,y_1)$.

Comment: @franticoreo: first write down these full conditionals by isolating the terms in $y_1$ (resp. $y_2$, $y_3$) in the joint and identify standard distributions. Note that the $y_i$'s are positive real numbers in $p(y_1,y_2,y_3)$.

Comment: This model from Besag is processed in [our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR) as well, as Example 10.1 (p.372).

Comment: @Xi'an is it correct to state that $p(y_i|y_{-i})\propto \exp(-(1-\psi_{i, j}y_j)y_i)\quad i\neq j$ then we can do the gibbs sampler

Comment: Almost there is a sum missing from the exponent.